# Is there a way to stop a docker container, if a linked/upstream container is gone?

Tags: docker

In my use case, I am having two docker-images 'A' and 'B', where 'B' kind of relies on an exposed port of container A.

```
# pseudo, Setup1
$ docker run -d A
aaaaa
$ docker run -d --link aaaaa B
bbbbb
```

This works just fine. If container "aaaaa" is not available, docker won't let me start container of image B

```
# pseudo, Setup2
$ docker run -d --link aaaaa B
docker: Error response from daemon: Cannot link to a non running container
```

Just fine.

Now, in my "Setup1", I am stopping container "aaaaa". Container "bbbbb" will just keep running. In my use case, I would like to stop this "dependent" container now. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Docker 1.12. introduces [HEALTHCHECK](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/healthcheck%20%22HEALTHCHECK%22). As an ugly workaround, it works to place a *killall* or similar in the HEALTHCHECK-script.

Maybe you are searching for [docker-compose -> depends on](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/dependson).